# javascript is unable to working on infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website which have multiple posts and each post have a like button with auto timeout modal popup. When scrolling down, more posts loaded with infinite.js. Which load the posts.
**The problem** : In the first page the like button with timeout modal popup does work. But when the posts load in infinitely the modal popup is not working anymore.

```
<main role="main" class="container infinite-container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 infinite-item">
        <article class="content-section">
            <div class="post-bar">
                <button href="" class="like2-btn btn-outline-dark">
                  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </button>
                <!-- modal-->
                 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                     post liked
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <------>
                <p class="text">Tab the button for write a post</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
 </div>
```

```
{% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">More</a>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/shortcuts/infinite.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
        element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
        handler: function(direction) {

    },
    offset: 'bottom-in-view',
    onBeforePageLoad: function () {
    $('.spinner-border').show();
    },
    onAfterPageLoad: function () {
    $('.spinner-border').hide();
    }


    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.like2-btn').click(()=>{
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
            setTimeout(() => {
                $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
            },1000);
        });
    });

    </script>
```

first it loads 10 posts after scrolling bottom down 10 posts loads again which is done by infinite.js
I want to add the same modal popup function to every infinite container. But somehow its not working in the infinite container instead of the first page which is already loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). Basically, you won't attach the listener to elements, but rather to the page and make your handler dependent on the event details.

So (in vanilla) it would be something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('like2-btn') || e.target.closest('.like2-btn')) {
    // do sth...
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes and no, new standards require you to be really good on the passive select and in some cases you'll not be able to push this as an element may require  Event.stopPropagation(). Would suggest grabbing other elements to sort this need if it comes up.

Comment: @blanknamefornow so will it work? I mean the answer which is submitted by marks

Comment: Yes till you need to prevent certain actions that'd occur on click. Form submissions/etc.

Comment: @blanknamefornow sure thing. if you have a special case where you want to avoid bubbling you might need to reinitiate the listener manually for the new nodes or attach the handler to a deeper dom node instead of the document-element. But yes, for you this will work Cavin

Comment: @Cavinblake if the answer solved your question make sure to mark the answer as correct so it's visible from the overview that you question is resolved. thanks!